# Get 401 status code from request header

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am facing issue to retrieve the status code of response for unauthorised request using axis library in react. Below code snippet logs 200 but not 401.

```
axios({
           url: url,
           method: 'get', // default\
           timeout: 10000,
           responseType: 'json', // default
           maxContentLength: 2000,
     }).then((response) => {
    console.log("Status", response.status); //logs 200 but not 401
    })
```

I know that there will not be response sent for 401 but I could see the status code 401 in header of the request. I am not sure whether accessing status code from request header will be good idea but as there is no response hence no place to check it. So any idea how can I get the status code from request header? any other ideas will also be appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`400` status codes are errros that are catched.

```
axios({
    url: url,
    method: 'get', // default\
    timeout: 10000,
    responseType: 'json', // default
    maxContentLength: 2000,
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log("Status", response.status); //status code 200
    }).catch(e=>{
        console.log("Status", e.response.status); //status code 300 and 400
})
```

Check the axios [documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors) for handling errors.

Comment: there is no status defined on 'e' here. I did try this but its giving me an undefined.

Comment: thanks nrgwsth for sharing the documentation and I tried the axiom.get option and I am able to get the status. But the problem if I am using  axios.get is, I am not able to configure the request properties such as timeout,responsetype,maxContentLength etc if I use axis.get. I can easily configure in axis({ url:url,method:get,timeout:1000....}) format and for this, catch is not returning the status.